# Execute a Shell Script from php?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, php

I'm trying to generate Android `apk` files from shell script, I want to execute a shell script file from PHP. When I run the shell script in the terminal, it works perfectly. If I try to run the script using PHP, the shell script doesn't execute all the commands. The **ls** command in shell script works perfectly, but when executing using PHP, other commands does'nt work. I'm using xampp server in a Linux environment.

My shell script

```
cd /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/msvep4247-inghamautogroup-pulse-and/
./gradlew assembleDebug
cp -fr app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /opt/lampp/htdocs/sample/apk
ls
```

Shell script `ls` output

> app autolead_data_format.pdf build build.gradle cheek gradle
>   gradle.properties gradlew gradlew.bat lib local.properties
>   msvep4247-inghamautogroup-pulse-and.iml settings.gradle

My PHP script

```
   <?php
      echo shell_exec('ls');
      echo shell_exec('./generateApk.sh');
   ?>
```

PHP script `ls` output

> generateApk.sh generate.php APK

Note: `ls` outputs file names in the folder

I set all the file permissions for shell script in the xampp server. Can anyone describe where I'm mistaken? Awaiting responses . .

Comment: Add on the begin of your script `source ~/.bashrc` and try again

Comment: can you please explain little ellobrate ?

Comment: The script name is with cap G, replace php line to be `echo shell_exec('./GenerateApk.sh');`

Comment: The Script working perfectly, when it's run from php, not responding

Comment: Check please my previous comment about "G"

Comment: sorry ! now i updated the question